# Critical section in parallel make file

Tags: c, makefile, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallelize an old Makefile.

In fact I need to make sure that some generator scripts are called *not parallel* before the compiling procedure starts.

The generators are always called before the compile. Is there any way to establish a somewhat critical section in a makefile?

The Makefile is messy, I'd prefer not to post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the rules for the generated files in a separate Makefile, and do something like this:

```
generated-sources :
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Generators
```

However, with GNU Make, this will be parallel by default.  You'll need to suppress it, and the manual isn't exactly clear how you would do that.  Maybe some combination of the following would work, depending on which implementations of make you wish to support:

- Pass the `-j1` flag:

  ```
  generated-sources :
          $(MAKE) -j1 -f Makefile.Generators
  ```
- Suppress `MAKEFLAGS` options:

  ```
  generated-sources :
          $(MAKE) -f Makefile.Generators MAKEFLAGS=
  ```
- Suppress parallel execution with the following line in `Makefile.Generators`:

  ```
  .NOTPARALLEL :
  ```

Comment: a note on the .NOTPARALLEL option: That target will ignore any pre-reqs specified.  Any makefile containing this target will be forced to serial building.  So, you could put stuff that needs to build serially in a separate makefile and add the .NOTPARALLEL target.  This differs from the ClearCase build tool Clearmake in that it allows you to specify a set of targets that will be treated as mutually exclusive w/respect to parallel building.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a rule that runs all of the scripts, and then make sure all of your other rules depend on that rule.

```
all: ${SOURCES} scripts

scripts: last_script


first_script:
    ./script1.sh

second_script: first_script
    ./script2.sh

last_script: second_script
    ./script3.sh

source1.o: source1.c scripts
    gcc source1.c -c -o source1.o
```

Comment: the problem is that these scripts are called with attributes from inside the makefile, but it is the right direction, thanks

Comment: what if i have something like this?